# .net 8 Docker HttpClient time out

Tags: .net, docker, docker-desktop

I'm using .net 8 and Docker Desktop with linux container.

I'm making a request from API in docker to another api and it's not working and if i'm a call to external api with domain for example https://somedomian/api - it's working find.

I have this error (localhost to localhost with HttpClient in Docker container):

```
 The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 30 seconds elapsing
```

Docker file:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

 

FROM comp-artifactory.bb.comp.gov.com/docker/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base

USER app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 443

#RUN dotnet dev-certs https --trust

 

FROM comp-artifactory.bb.comp.gov.com/docker/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["netTestAApi/netTestAApi.csproj", "netTestAApi/"]

RUN dotnet nuget add source http://comp-artifactory.bb.comp.gov.com:8082/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/nuget -n artifactory

RUN dotnet nuget disable source nuget.org

RUN dotnet restore "./netTestAApi/./netTestAApi.csproj"

COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/netTestAApi"

RUN dotnet build "./netTestAApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

 

FROM build AS publish

ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

RUN dotnet publish "./netTestAApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

 

COPY ./netTestAApi/crt/1.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

COPY ./netTestAApi/crt/2.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

RUN update-ca-certificates

 

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

COPY --from=build-env /app/out/netTestAApi.SwaggerExtensions.xml ./

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "netTestAApi.dll"]
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi can i know where do you get the url ? is it from ENV file ? If yes, there may be some configuration error there. I need to see your dockerfile first

Comment: i have added the docker file

Comment: Where do you get the api url ? is it through env or what ?

Comment: By default its Dev

Comment: When connecting to localhost, are you intending to connect to the host running the container? If so, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/12567640

Comment: As an unrelated aside, you're adding certificates to the publish stage of your container, not the final image. To be able to use them in the eventual container you'll need to move that to the final stage.

Comment: I did it, still the same :(